# SQL Server installation location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

What is the best practice recommendations for installing SQL Server 2012 or 2014 with regards the installation files location. Can the installation files location resides on the system drive or should it have a dedicated drive?

Comment: Drive configuration and the distribution of files is a broad topic that depends on your hardware setup and your requirements. There are specific articles addressing best practices for installing SQL Server [on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+practice+recommendations+for+installing+SQL+Server+2012%2F2014+with+regards+the+installation+files+location&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Please make your question a lot more specific if you want a better answer.

Comment: @DanielHutmacher I disagree that this question is too broad. The poster asked for the best practices as to installation files location. It could be considered too broad if the question was about the physical storage - it is a much deeper topic.

Answer (score 2):

For production instances it is recommended to create separate partitions for the following elements of SQL Server:

- data files
- transaction log files
- tempdb files

Some people also suggest to install SQL Server on a dedicated partition instead of the C: drive but I think it is an overkill and does not bring any benefit. The installation itself cannot grow out of control. System databases other than tempdb can (theoretically) do that. I would also recommend putting them and their log files on a different partition.

You should definetely not put data/tempdb/log files on the same partition as the OS, because if you run out of space for say tempdb, the OS might not be able to perform correctly when out of space.

Also there is another big topic of data separation on different physical drives for security/performance reasons but I will not go into that.